# Redeem a promotional code using Stripe api in C# MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, stripe-payments

I'm trying to figure out how to let a user redeem a discount/ promo code in Stripe.

Looking at the documentation I think should retrieve the code using PromotionCodeService() so I can then get the discount amount to apply to the subscription, something like

```
var service = new PromotionCodeService();
service.Get("promo_1HMxuf2eZvKYlo2CmGXSyhRx");
```

But I cannot seem to get access to that service as I can the ProductService(), CouponService() etc.
Can anyone point me to any example code on where this has been done before, I'm sure it's a common enough thing.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally the integration would be

- you accept some input from the user for the user-facing code they entered
- use https://stripe.com/docs/api/promotion_codes/list#list_promotion_code-code to look up the promo code objects related
- create the user's subscription and pass PromotionCode in the SubscriptionCreateOptions with the ID of one of the objects(https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/discounts/codes#applying-promotion-codes)

> But I cannot seem to get access to that service as I can the ProductService(), CouponService() etc

That almost certainly means you're using an old version of the stripe-dotnet library from before when that service was added, so upgrading should fix that. https://github.com/stripe/stripe-dotnet/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#37290---2020-08-05

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that out as soon as I can